# If Blank Cell Shift Cells Up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to enter data on column D based on column A without the blank cells.

```
  A B C D F
1 X     X
2       Y
3 Y     Z    
4 Z
5
```

I need a formula for the formula bar since column A changes dynamically. So manually sorting the data using excel settings for rows et cetera won't help.

Comment: Hi.. Welcome to SO .. Refer [this link](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/return-the-non-blank-items-in-a-list.htm) .. Its an array formula .. copy the formula .. paste it in formula bar and press control shift enter .. `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$5)),ROW($A$1:$A$5),""),ROW(A1))),"")` and then copy he cell and paste down .

Comment: In cell `D1` you can enter with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER as this is an array formula: `=IF(ROWS(D$2:D5)>COUNTA(A:A),"",INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(A$1:A$11<>"",ROW(A$1:A$11)),ROWS(D$2:D5))))`

Comment: @NareshBhople Thank you for that answer it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

**For Excel 365 only:**

In **D1** enter:

```
=FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A))
```

[image]

*(if you do not have Excel 365, ignore this answer)*